# Comparing >=2 groups of unequal size categorical data

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, count-data

I have data that looks like this:

```
     Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3
     -------- ---------  --------
Obj1    4         1          6
Obj2    7         3          9
....
Objn    2         9          2
```

OR

```
     Group 1 | Group 2 
     -------- ---------
Obj1    1         0   
Obj2    2         3   
....
Objn    0         7
```

The slight complicating factor is that the sample sizes in the groups can be different (i.e. the column sums can be different).

In both cases, the null hypothesis I want to test is that there's no difference in the distribution of objects between the groups.

For either the 2 or >2 group case, what is the most appropriate test? It seemed that

- the Chi-square test doesn't make sense because of the large number of degrees of freedom that I can have, and that the column sums can be quite large numbers, too.
- the multinomial exact test seemed to fit the bill? but does it mean that I have to convert the counts as proportions (along the column)?

Would love your thoughts and suggestions! Thanks.

A picture is a thousand words: essentially, is the distribution of blue bars different to the orange ones?

[image]

Comment: There is a `count data` tag but nothing in the description declares these values as counts. Also there are dots behind some values but not behind others. Is that a decimal separator? If yes, how can these be count data?

Comment: The chi-squared test makes perfect sense under these conditions.  The usual rule of thumb limiting its application to tables where all expected counts exceed 5 doesn't apply to large tables.  When in doubt, a quick simulation will indicate whether chi-squared p-values can be trusted.  A more fundamental concern is *why are you doing this?* When you have such a rich dataset (large counts and large numbers of objects), the question "are these groups independent" usually isn't terribly interesting and will often be resolved in the negative only because the sample is large.

Comment: Apologies @Bernhard I realised the dots were there because of my Mac. Thanks for the spot. It's been fixed.

Comment: What is your goal? For example do you want to find an object that has a significantly different ratio than the rest of the objects? Or maybe you want to test each object individually against a fixed ratio? Or maybe you want to check if the groups are different vs the same? Many possibilities..

Comment: @whuber thanks, I wasn't aware that the chi-square test _would_ make sense here. I've always operated under the assumption that the chi squared-test is assessing if the variables (obj1, obj2, .... objn vs. group1, group2... groupn) are independent?

I'm doing this because the distribution of objects characterises the group, and I really want to say that groups A and B are (not) significantly different. Challenge is, as you say, with such large sample sizes, I feel like everything would be deemed significant??

Comment: @KaPy3141 I just mentioned but essentially, is the distribution of objects in Group1 different to the distribution of objects in group2?

Comment: @AnonymousScientist: So as whuber mentioned, a Chi square makes sense. You don't necessarily have to compress it's information to the final X-value but you can look at each Pearson-residual individually to check if a particular cell seems particularly different from what you would expect in an independent distribution.

Comment: Amazing, okay, I did include a figure there for reference but I'll go with a chi-square test then!

Comment: Sorry one more thing @whuber what did you mean by a simulation in this case?

Comment: Sorry about being vague: simulation is often used in this setting in the form of a bootstrap or permutation test.

Comment: Ah right, so like permute the group IDs (since n_objects >> n_groups), then run a chi2 test for a N objects x 2 groups contingency table over and over again?

Comment: Think visualization. Look into correspondence analysis.

Comment: The testing can be much simpler than that: fit a model to the data; generate many synthetic datasets according to the model; compute the chi-squared statistic for each one; examine the distribution of those simulated chi-squared statistics.  You will find strong, clear evidence that your two groups differ.